How to iterate through a python list to get each additional list element?
I have a python list that I need to iterate through to get the additional consecutive element.
I'm trying to make a string from every other consecutive element in my list named data
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ...]
I need to turn this into a string that reads like...
data_string = "1, 3, 6, 10"
The list data can have any number of elements and may change, but the string should always to consist of elements 1,3, 6, 10, 15, 21, and so on.
I've tried running the following function...
def create_lists(values_list):
    result = [[]]
    for value in values_list[1:]:
        new_lists = [curr_list + [value] for curr_list in result]
        result.extend(new_lists)
    return result

result = create_lists(values_list)
print(result)

This only prints out separate lists with individual elements.
I'm new to python and having trouble.  Any ideas?

By "additional consecutive element." do you mean the 1st, 3rd, 6th... elements? Ie if data = [9,5,3,1,5,10] do you want 9, 3, 10?

Please explain exactly what "additional consecutive element" means.

It's OK to be new, but it still helps to share an attempt you made, to show what you tried and what you thought might work, even if it didn't. You can edit the question to include some code.

Based on the latest comment:
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

i, c, out = 0, 2, []
while i < len(data):
    out.append(str(data[i]))
    i += c
    c += 1

print(", ".join(out))

Prints:
1, 3, 6, 10


You can use the accumulate() from itertools:
from itertools import accumulate

def _prefix_sum(N):
    L = [i + 1 for i in range(N)]
    psum = list(accumulate(L))
    return psum


print(_prefix_sum(13))




If you want to have a string output:
from itertools import accumulate


def _prefix_sum(N):
    L = [i + 1 for i in range(N)]
    return ', '.join(map(str, accumulate(L)))

print(_prefix_sum(13))



Prints
1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91


Comments

May as well drop L and replace it with range(1, N + 1), avoiding an unnecessary temporary list (and letting range do all the simple math work more efficiently than manually adding one to each result). - ShadowRanger

from itertools import accumulate

_prefix_sum = lambda N: ', '.join(map(str, accumulate(range(1, N + 1))))

print(_prefix_sum(13))



Edit
For finding prefix sum in an array, you can use a set():
def _filter(L):
    L.sort()
    curr, res, psums = 0, '', set()
    full_sum = sum(L)
    for num in L:
        curr += num
        psums.add(curr)
        if num in psums:
            res += f"{num},"
        if curr > full_sum:
            break

    return res[:-1]


print(_filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]))
print(_filter([1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 40, 20]))


Prints
1,3,6,10
1,3,40


There are more efficient approaches, that can be used, such as binary search.

May as well drop L and replace it with range(1, N + 1), avoiding an unnecessary temporary list (and letting range do all the simple math work more efficiently than manually adding one to each result).

Are you sure they want an accumulation? My reading of the question is they want the 1th, 3rd, 6th... element. They stop at 10 because there is no 15th element.

Yes.  @Loocid is right.  It should iterate through several elements in the original list

@CharlesJr Is the list Natural Numbers or is it just any list?

@Loocid is correct it should work through a large lists of elements from the original data list.  I'm assuming I can change prefix_sum value to include all possible elements?
